# Using pNotify as drop-in replacement for javascript confirmation dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net, pnotify

I have javascript confirmations working inline and as function, however can't figure out how to implement with PNotify confirmation dialog. Ideally I can just replace confirm('Sure?') with pconfirm('Sure?') and return true/false. It is .Net app and primarily used in onClientClick event to confirm LinkButton execution client-side.

PNotify Confirm and Cancel events only fire if pconfirm returns false:

```
function pconfirm(title){
  (new PNotify({
    title: title,
    icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign',
    hide: false,
    confirm: {
      confirm: true
    },
    buttons: {
      closer: false,
      sticker: false
    },
    history: {
      history: false
    },
    addclass: 'stack-modal',
    stack: {
      'dir1': 'down',
      'dir2': 'right',
      'modal': true
    }
  })).get().on('pnotify.confirm', function() {
    //alert('ok');
    return true;
  }).on('pnotify.cancel', function() {
    //alert('cancel');
    return false;
  });
  return false;
}
```

I've created Fiddle with working javascript and failing PNotify:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lmeyers/3YNtc/9/)

Answer (score 1):

Answered my own question:

```
$(".confirmLink").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var targetUrl = $(this).attr("href");

  (new PNotify({
    title: $(this).data("title") || 'Are you sure?',
    icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign',
    hide: false,
    confirm: {
      confirm: true
    },
    buttons: {
      closer: false,
      sticker: false
    },
    history: {
      history: false
    },
    addclass: 'stack-modal',
    stack: {
      'dir1': 'down',
      'dir2': 'right',
      'modal': true
    }
  })).get().on('pnotify.confirm', function() {
    window.location.href = targetUrl;
  }).on('pnotify.cancel', function() {
    // do nothing
  });

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lmeyers/3YNtc/10/)